# Directly Computable Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We call a homomorphism $f$ defined on a permutation or a matrix group $G$
directly computable if there is an efficient method of evaluating $f(g)$
directly from $g$, for all $g$ in $G$. I can not understand this definition exactly? I need your explanation? 
example:If $G$ is an intransitive or imprimitive permutation group, then its induced
action on one of its orbits, or its induced action on the blocks of
imprimitivity is a directly computable homomorphism.

Comment: That isn't a rigorous definition, unless you have a rigorous definition of "efficient method of evaluating f(g)" in mind.

Comment: Need to say, this definition belongs to computational group theory.

Comment: can anyone give some details on this notion: "reducible matrix group that xes a subspace". I mean what is fixing subspace?

Comment: Try writing an algorithm to evaluate $f(g)$ given $g$ and the points in an orbit, or given $g$ and the partition of the points into blocks. You should be able to compute it using only $n$ evaluations of $x^g$ for $x$ a point and $n$ the size of the orbit or $n$ the number of blocks, aka, linearly in the input size.

Comment: A reducible $n\times n$ matrix group $G$ over a field $K$ is one in which there is a subspace $V \leq K^n$ such that $vg \in V$ whenever $v \in V$ and $g \in G$. The induced actions on $V$ and $K^n/V$ are directly computable. Again, prove this by writing down algorithms to evaluate them.

Comment: which evaluations must be considered ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two essentially different ways of defining homomorphisms $f:G \to H$ on finite permutation or matrix groups $G$ that arise in computational group theory.

In the first method, which is what you are calling "directly computable", it is possible to compute $f(g)$ directly from $g$, without reference to the rest of the group $G$.

For example, suppose that $G = S_3 \times S_3$ acting on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, where the two direct factors are acting naturally on $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6\}$, and $f:G \to S_3$ is the projection onto the second direct factor. Then you can easily compute $f(g)$ directly from $g$, just by looking at the action of $g$ on the second orbit. For example, $f((1,3)(4,6,5)) = (1,3,2)$.

The action of a reducible matrix group on a fixed subspace is another example. Here you would need a preprocessing stage to compute a change of basis matrix so that the fixed subspace was spanned by the first few basis vectors. Then, to compute $f(g)$, you would first apply the basis change to $g$, and then you could read off $f(g)$ from the top left block of the resulting matrix.

The other way that homomorphisms can be defined is by fixing a generating set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_r\}$ of $G$ and specifying $f(x_i)$ for each $x_i$. Then (assuming that this does really does define a homomorphism), $f(g)$ is uniquely determined for each $g \in G$. Such homomorphisms are not directly computable, because to compute $f(g)$ you need to express $g$ as a word in the $x_i$.

Since this problem of expressing $g$ in the $x_i$ is difficult in general, there are various techniques for making it more practical. One technique is to introduce new intermediate generators that are themselves defined as words in the $x_i$, and then use the intermediate generators in your word for $g$. So, for permutation groups, you could extend the generating set to a so-called *strong generating set*. There is a more general approach to this problem that uses *Straight Line Programs*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your exact answer. Can we use this notion in order to find subgroups, for instance the subgroups of general linear groups over finite fields?

Comment: It is used in algorithms for finding normal subgroups that arise as kernels of directly computable homomorphisms: for example the action of a matrix group on a fixed subspace, or on a system of blocks of imprimitivity. The problem is that you do not automatically have generators of the kernels, and the usual technique is to find a collection of random elements of the kernel with a view to finding a complete generating set with high probability.